# Delete a CSS propery you dont have access to edit

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a complete Bootstrap grid system. I am now uploading my code to a CMS system, and can see there is some CSS from the backend, there is messing up my grid.

If I untick the following code in the inspector window, everything is looking perfect. When the following code is ticked in the inspector window everything is messed up. Is it possible to overwrite this code somehow, so the class is not used?

```
.cms-area img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use !important in such cases but use it sparingly. Best is to remove the unwanted code and not use !important. !important might cause issues later that are difficult to debug. If possible include your css after other css is included in the code. In CSS, rules that appear later take precedence over earlier rules

Edit:

Set width to auto instead of 100% to fix your alignment issue

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I have to remove the `.cms-area img {
    width: 100%;
}`, and not keep that.

Comment: Ok I see, then use a different class name then and apply your styles to that class. That way CSSs would not conflict

Comment: I am not able to follow, can you please clarify

Comment: Yes it was also bad written

Comment: If you fx right click the snapchat element, and click on the picture - you will get the class `.cms-area img`. If you untick this class all the elements is aligning with eachother.

Comment: set width to auto instead of 100%

Comment: Nice that solved the problem. Thank you. Will you set it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Below given is the ideal way to manage css since it allows you to attribute your style content and lets you override the style already applied elsewhere.

```
.cms-area .your-class img {
    width: <your choice>;
}
```

Comment: `width: auto;` would be the best bet.